# Disconnect() method of Django Channels WebSocketConsumer not being called

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

> I have the following class which is inheriting from the `WebSocketConsumer`:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from channels.exceptions import StopConsumer

class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
   
       def connect(self):
          self.accept()
       
       def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
          data = json.loads(text_data)
          n = data["number"]
          
          for i in range(n):
              self.send(json.dumps({"number":i}))
              
       def disconnect():
           raise StopConsumer
```

> The input JSON contains only a single parameter called `number`. I am testing this code using a chrome plugin. When I open the connection and close it without sending any message, the disconnect method is executed as expected.

> When the number is for example 100 and the loop inside the receive method is not yet finished and I disconnect in between, the disconnect method is not called and I get the following error:

```
ERROR - server - Exception inside application: Attempt to send on a closed protocol.
File "MyConsumer.py", line 2, in receive
    self.send
File "python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 69, in send
    {"type": "websocket.send", "text": text_data},
  File "python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 107, in send
    self.base_send(message)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 64, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 78, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 220, in send
    return await self.real_send(message)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/daphne/server.py", line 198, in handle_reply
    protocol.handle_reply(message)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/daphne/ws_protocol.py", line 179, in handle_reply
    self.serverSend(message["text"], False)
  File "site-packages/daphne/ws_protocol.py", line 223, in serverSend
    self.sendMessage(content.encode("utf8"), binary)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py", line 2216, in sendMessage
    raise Disconnected("Attempt to send on a closed protocol")
  Attempt to send on a closed protocol
```

> I want to be able to disconnect even when the processing for a given number has not been completed. Is this not possible with `WebSocketConsumer` ? Have I misunderstood the synchronous nature of `WebSocketConsumer`?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into same issue and did some research about how to overcome this issue.

When we use WebsocketConsumer, the disconnect method will not be called until the current execution is not complete. It is because of an issue in a package called daphne (Found this information from their Github page).

But here is a trick that I used. If you are using a `loop`, create a separate method for that and call that method using a thread. Then you will be able to call the disconnect method while your loop is still running. Maybe you want to stop the execution when disconnect is called, so you can google it out or use the method I have used below:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from channels.exceptions import StopConsumer
import threading

class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
   
       def connect(self):
          self.accept()
       
       def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
          data = json.loads(text_data)
          n = data["number"]
        
          self.stop = False  # A flag to break out from for loop
          self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.action)  # This thread will work same but 
          self.thread.start()                                 # also allows to call disconnect()

       def action(self, n):
          for i in range(n):
              self.send(json.dumps({"number":i}))
              if self.stop:
                  break

              
       def disconnect():
           self.stop = True  # This will trigger the termination of loop
           del self.thread  # Maybe you also want to delete the thread
           raise StopConsumer
```

You can adjust the logic where you want to call these methods.

Answer (score 0):

when user connection closed and you continue to send data to it channels will raise exception
use `try ... except... block`

```
def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
    data = json.loads(text_data)
    n = data["number"]
          
    try:
        for i in range(n):
            self.send(json.dumps({"number":i}))
    except Exception as e:# i don't remember exact exception, will change this soon
        print(e) #you can log this situation or do what ever you want
```

Comment: The exception is from autobahn.exception.Disconnected. But is this a clean way of implementation. I mean the program is trying to send on a closed connection. And it is not always that this exception is raised. I want to be able to close the connection in a clean manner.

Comment: you have `for` `loop` in your code, program will try to finish it. you can try to check is connection active before sending to channel , but i think the try except block is more clear way

Comment: I understand what you are trying to imply but why is the disconnect method not being called? Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: your loop is running, disconnect should happen when it finished, but exception was happened  before, that is why you don't get to disconnect method

Comment: The way I understand it is that disconnect should happen when the websocket client closes the connection and an event is received. From the Django Documentation: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html#closing-consumers

Comment: you may think of it as a a queue. when user disconnected this event goes to the end of queue, and you need to wait while all existing tasks complete

Comment: Are you sure that this is how it has been implemented?

Comment: you can check it. add `try ...except` and see what happened

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217652/discussion-between-kishan-kishore-and-andrey-maslov).